# What cross-platform Synergy GUI are available?

Tags: synergy, cross-platform

I am looking for a cross platform Synergy GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any one GUI that works on OSX/Linux/Windows.  However, the raw config file is easy to read and understand.  It is well documented, and only takes a moment to set up.

http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html

You basically need to call out screens (computers you are controling), links (computer1 is up/down/left/right of computer2), and aliases (host names of the computers).

That being said, http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/ works on OSX and Linux, and I believe the windows version comes with a GUI.